# What does this Windows crash dump mean?

Tags: crash, windows-server-2003, crash-dumps

Yesterday  my system software got crashed on WINDOWS 2003 server. The Core shown below.

```
  kernel32.dll!_RaiseException@16()  + 0x3c bytes 

  rpcrt4.dll!_RpcpRaiseException@4()  + 0x21 bytes 

  rpcrt4.dll!_NdrGetBuffer@12()  - 0x1d3fe bytes 

  rpcrt4.dll!_NdrClientCall2()  + 0x132 bytes 

  hnetcfg.dll!_FwOpenDynamicFwPort@16()  + 0x1d bytes 

  hnetcfg.dll!_IcfOpenDynamicFwPort@12()  + 0x6a bytes 

  mswsock.dll!_WSPBind@16()  + 0xa55 bytes 

  ws2_32.dll!_bind@12()  + 0x4e bytes 

  sal.dll!s_SktBind(s_Socket * sp=0x05943800, SAL_AddrBuf_t 
* addrp=0x057cfe00,unsigned int addrsz=0x00000042)  Line 76 + 0x14 bytes C++

  sal.dll!SAL_SktBind(SAL_SktHandle_t * sh=0x05943800, SAL_AddrBuf_t 
*addrp=0x057cfe00, unsigned int addrsz=0x00000042)  Line 101 + 0xe bytes C++
```

Note: sal.dll is my software module. it is calling System Call bind() from our function SktBind()

Could you please tell, why it was crashed ?  and how can I solve this problem.

If you have any comments or suggestion , please share with me.

Comment: Long lines of dashes throw off your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The call to [bind()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737550%28VS.85%29.aspx) from function s_SktBind() in sal.dll has caused the crash.

The first thing I would check is that you bind() is being called with proper arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like kernel programming to me (re the tag).

Which process faulted? Looks like your program, since you have line number info.

What was the fault? AV? Or some other exception?

Paste the line and surrounding code that crashed. (Line 101 of the file that defines SAL_SktBind).

Answer (score 0):

[hnetcfg.dll](http://www.processlibrary.com/directory/files/hnetcfg/) is a process associated with Home Networking Configuration Manager from Microsoft Corporation.

Search Microsoft support for relevant articles (e.g. [maybe this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308007))

The code that is the origin of the problem seems to be dealing with networking. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have posted the full call stack, but sal.dll is a dll that is provided by Novell and this is from where the error originates. So you might want to check if a newer version of this dll is available.